# Does Star Trek - Bridge Crew support any form of couch co-op on the PS4?

Tags: ps4, star-trek-bridge-crew

With all of the write-ups and videos I have seen, I thought I would have found this answer by now.  Simply put, can my friend and I each grab a controller for my PS4 Pro, and sit down together to play the game?

In my situation, I would be looking to take advantage of the non-VR mode for now, as I do not yet have the VR gear.  So, it really is your basic old-school couch co-op scenario.

I haven't purchased the game yet...this answer would influence my decision, hence my asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, Bridge Crew does not support couch co-op.

**You can play without a PSVR, but you're still limited to 1 player per PS4.**

If you have 2 PS4s and 2 TVs, you could play in the same room. But that's obviously not what you're looking for.